# Removing graphics Nvidia/Radeon driver without going headless

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, radeon

Experimenting with switching from an Nvidia to a Radeon card, I cannot install the Radeon driver upfront as ubuntu software center says it conflicts with the nvidia one. Makes sense. However uninstalling the Nvidia driver, will I be confined to a terminal session, or can I still use the unity desktop after that point?

More broadly, how can I safely and easily switch between the two drivers and back?

[image]

Comment: I would open the Additional Drivers app and use out to switch to the generic video driver, then to `fglrx`.

Comment: I assume you mean the Additional Drivers tab in `Software & Updates`. What do you mean by "use out"?

Comment: Whoops. Use it*. And yes, I mean that.

Comment: Can I safely switch to fglrx before switching the cards in the box??! or will that preclude using the desktop till the cards have been swapped?

Comment: fglrx won't show up until you put the AMD card in. Switch to the generic driver, put the new card in. It should work fine

Comment: This is also what you said about http://askubuntu.com/a/682167/208696 :) which didn't work. Further, reading your last comment you don't account for installing fglrx in the first place. I take this with a grain of salt. As is, this style of answering is rather counter-productive, sorry to say that.

Comment: Ubuntu will automatically recognize that an AMD card has been put in in place of NVIDIA. If you uninstall the NVIDIA driver, it'll automatically switch itself back to the generic NVIDIA drivers. When you put in the AMD card, Ubuntu will start using the generic AMD driver. You can then install fglrx. You won't be kicked to a terminal by uninstalling the NVIDIA driver, since Ubuntu will automatically replace it. In actuality, you should be able to leave it as it is and just swap the cards and switch drivers after the reboot, as both generic drivers are part of Ubuntu and don't need to install

Comment: Thanks, this would have been "the accepted answer" if it were up to me.

Comment: It is up to you. I can just copy-paste it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To safely switch between graphics drivers, you should switch to the generic Noveau driver. That will remove the old driver while still keeping access to the desktop.

Unless you manually installed drivers, you can switch by opening Software and Sources, and going to the Additional Drivers tab.

Comment: Thanks but I don't really dig this. Isn't Noveau just for Nvidia? Following this advice how come I would still be able to access the desktop with a Radeon card and the Noveau driver, at the stage that I switch the cards?

Comment: Conversely, installing the Radeon (fglrx) driver while the Nvidia card is still the one plugged in, will that keep the desktop working up until I physically replace the cards?

Comment: Like @Zachary1 said, you need to actually switch the cards. If you switch the the generic driver, Ubuntu will automatically detect and load the generic AMD driver, but only if it's actually plugged in.